# How to know the eme spec version from cobalt code or other?

Tags: chromium, cobalt, eme

1. how to clarify the eme version at cobalt version
2. how to know cobalt from Chromium version

Browser  SDK version    Chromium    EME spec

Cobalt   11.107588    ?           ?
Cobalt   11.153049    ?           ?
Cobalt   16.162639    ?           ?

Thank you

Comment: Browser/SDK version/Chromium /EME spec      for example   Cobalt/11.107588/versionXXX/emexxx

Comment: Note that EME specification is not Chromium-specific, it's maintained by W3C.

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt doesn't track the precise version of EME in the code. However, taking the latest LTS version of Cobalt should be enough to meet YouTube certification requirements in any given year.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Can you tell me how can I get the chromium version which the Cobalt use ? such as cobalt release 11 or cobalt 19. Thank you

Comment: Can you please ask this as a separate question? I believe that other users may benefit from the answer.

Comment: Also, please upvote the answer if you consider it useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have asked a separate question.